# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter dynamic layout

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

Sorry for bad english. Guys, the question is as follows. Is it possible to dynamically change the properties of the markup explain: There is a correspondence between the 2 users, and there is 1 for counting the messages themselves. Here is a method to initialize and configure the adapter:

```
 mFBAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatMessage, FirechatMsgViewHolder>(
        ChatMessage.class,
       // chat_message - my msg layout
        R.layout.chat_message,
        FirechatMsgViewHolder.class,
        mDatabaseReference.child(romName)
) {

    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(FirechatMsgViewHolder firechatMsgViewHolder, ChatMessage chatMessage, int i) {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);

        firechatMsgViewHolder.msgText.setText(chatMessage.getText())          firechatMsgViewHolder.userText.setText(chatMessage.getName());


        if (mFirebaseUser.getPhotoUrl() == null) {
            firechatMsgViewHolder.userImage.setImageDrawable(
                    ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_36dp));
        } else {
            mUsername = mFirebaseUser.getDisplayName();
            mPhotoUrl = mFirebaseUser.getPhotoUrl().toString();
            Glide.with(ChatFragment.this).
                    load(chatMessage.getPhotoUrl()).into(firechatMsgViewHolder.userImage);
        }
    }
};

mFBAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
    @Override
    public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
        super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
        int chatMsgCount = mFBAdapter.getItemCount();
        int lastVisiblePosition = mLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
        if (lastVisiblePosition == -1 ||
                (positionStart >= (chatMsgCount - 1) && lastVisiblePosition == (positionStart - 1))) {
            mMsgRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(positionStart);
        }
    }
});

mMsgRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
mMsgRecyclerView.setAdapter(mFBAdapter);

mUsername = mFirebaseUser.getDisplayName().toString();
```

have the names of both participants, and I wanted to do something to help them do so, what message sent by the user to appear in his right, and adopted - on the left. There are constant and Gravity.LEFT Gravity.RIGHT, with which you can control the position of the code, but it is bolted. It was a variant type:

```
 if(mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName().equals(mUsername)){
    // gravity right...

} else {
    // gravity lef.....
}
```

but it did not work. There is some thought, can anyone come across?

Comment: Not entirely clear what you're asking. Can you explain it in more detail?

Comment: Oh sure. In short, how do I do so, what kind of message it was not a single line, as in 2: Messages of all users the left hand side, sent me - right.

Comment: The FirebaseUI sample app seems to do exactly what you're asking about: left/right align the children based on the sender. See https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/firebase/uidemo/database/ChatActivity.java#L155 and https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/firebase/uidemo/database/ChatActivity.java#L271

Comment: it's work,thank you!